# HTML hyperlink extending list in other file

Tags: javascript, html, extend

I have a image with hyperlink to another HTML file which includes list. The main goal is to click on that image and go to another HTML file and extend the item I clicked in first file. For example: In first file I have items with hyperlink- Bloody Mary, Mojito, Margarita and Pina colada. In second file I have extendable list with the same items. When I click on item (in first file), for example Mojito, it goes to second file and extends Mojito's recipe. Rest of cocktails stay unextended. How can I reach that?

File one

```
<article class="style1">
    <span class="image">
        <img src="images/pic01.jpg" alt="" />
    </span>
    <a href="SecondFile.html">
        <h2>Information</h2>
            <div class="content">
                <p>
                    Some info
                </p>
            </div>
    </a>
</article>
```

[File one picture. Clickable box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERMgx.png)


Second file

```
<button class="accordion">Mojito</button>
<div class="panel">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <p> Extendable Recipe </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
var acc = document.getElemntsByClassName("accordion");
var i;
for (i=0, i<acc.length, i++) {
   acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      this.classList.toggle("active");
      var panel = this.nextElemntSibling;
      if (panel.style.display==="block") {
         panel.style.display = "none";
      } else {
         panel.style.display = "block";
      }
  });
}
```

[File two picture. Extended list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zTIq.png)

Comment: Why is this tagged with `c++`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share variables between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21128692/share-variables-between-html-pages)

Comment: This should be tagged 'javascript' rather than 'c++'.

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a number of ways, the simplest would be to utilize existing frameworks such as bootstrap or materialize. Check out their documentation they both have collapsible/accordion components that you can insert with their pre built css classes, you can of course condition the class upon the click and therby accomplish what you are suggesting.