# How to send/get data from one local html file to another jusing Java script

Tags: javascript, android, html, webview

Pls help me.. I want to send a data from a variable form one html file to another. **with out using internet..** the html file will be run in a android webVIew. thank you **No PHP pls**

Comment: A similar question:

[Passing data between html pages][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/passing-data-between-html-pages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible. but you can use url params `file2.html?key=value&anotherKey=value`

Answer (score 0):

It’s not possible to share data between files, since *dead files* are by no means applications capable of handling data. It takes a browsing context to make them alive.

If you can’t use any underlying code to pass the data between documents, then your best shot is to pass the data between browsing contexts (inside a single webView those would be frames I guess.)