# pressing button on one page highlights button on new page

Tags: javascript, html, button

So i have two pages and one has a list of buttons (page a) and the other page only has one(page b). Im looking for a way that if you press the button on page b it will take me to page a with the second button with .focus() already targeting it. here are some links for the code i have written this is for page a http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/S96zw/

HTML page a

```
<button type="button" id="button0" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">button0</button><p></p>
<button type"button" id="button1" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">button1</button><p></p>
<button type"button" id="button2" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">button2</button><p></p>
<textarea id="myArea"></textarea>
<button type"button" id="button0" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">focus on button 0</button><p></p>
```

JAVASCRIPT (just used the same for both pages)

```
function reply_click(clicked_id){
  var id= clicked_id;
  var myTextArea = document.getElementById('myArea');
  myTextArea.innerHTML += id;
  document.getElementById(id).focus(); 
};
```

and this is for page b http://jsfiddle.net/posgarou/S96zw/

HTML 
     `<body>
        <textarea id="result"></textarea>
        <button type="button" id="return" onClick="reply_click(this.id)">Return</button>
    </body>`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do that using either a cookie or (better) local/sessionStorage.

On page b, you would include the following code:

```
sessionStorage["focusedButton"] = "buttonId";
```

and on page a, you would include the following:

```
if (sessionStorage["focusedButton"] != undefined) {
    document.getElementById(sessionStorage["buttonId"]).focus();
}
```

For more info, see [this earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/passing-data-between-html-pages).