# saving an array of objects in a session

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, session, dropzone.js

This is a snippet of my code that runs every time a file gets added to the uploader (`dropzone.js`). The files are not immediately uploaded but are rather stored in a queue. I would like to be able to maintain this queue throughout post backs.

```
        var myDropzone = this;
        var filesUploaded;
        myDropzone.on("addedfile", function () {
                filesUploaded = myDropzone.getQueuedFiles();
                myDropzone.queuedFiles = filesUploaded; // this should be set on each
// postback to be equal to the filesUpload that existed before the postback
            });
```

The files in `myDropzone.queuedFiles` should remain after a post back occurs. I would like to have the uploaded files still visible in the uploader, that way user does not need to re-select their files.

I'm new to web dev and I've tried using sessionStorage but I was unable to implement anything working. I'm working with JavaScript (jQuery), ASP.NET and using `dropzone.js` as the uploader.

I do realize that `myDropzone.queuedFiles = filesUploaded` should only be run when a post back has happened and we have saved the information from `filesUploaded` into something we can maintain and access after a postback. How would I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with `localStorage`? I think your problem is `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage`.

> HTML local storage provides two objects for storing data on the
>   client:
>
> **window.localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date.
>
> **window.sessionStorage** - stores data for one session (data is lost when
>   the tab is closed)

Take a look at these links:

[Pass datepicker object between pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692321/jquery-datepicker-highlight-date-selected-from-datepicker-in-a-calendar/30693831#30693831)

[HTML5 Local Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)