# Remain class from previous page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Simple question here, I've got a button with JavaScript that changes from ON to OFF changing it's `class` attribute.

So, the default value is **OFF**, and when you click it, swaps to **ON**. The problem is that everytime you navigate through the website's pages it always displays as **OFF** from default even if you selected **ON** previously.

Is it anyway with JavaScript or jQuery to remain the option selected from the previous page? I'm using `class` attribute to change the element from ON to OFF

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: JS retains no data from page to page by itself. If you want to store data between page loads (or even site visits) look in to using `sessionStorage`, `localStorage`, cookies or a server-side datastore. From what you've described I would say that `localStorage` is adequate in this case.

Comment: on click, send an ajax request to server, and keep the value in session.

Comment: Check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/passing-data-between-html-pages  .. Would any of these approaches solve your problem?

Comment: I will read about it, thanks everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways that comes to my mind where you can get the value from the previous page. In each case the previous page would need to store the data (option value) somewhere and the next page would need to load this data from there.

1. SERVER-SIDE Solution (Permanent Solution)

   - When user selects the option on the previous page, the page should then send the data to the server via AJAX, or using the `<form>` element. Server can then store the option into the database, file or session storage...
   - When you load the next page from the server, this page can be set to already include the data on loading or fetch it dynamically via AJAX.
2. CLIENT-SIDE Solution (Data persistency not guaranteed)

   - When user selects the option on the previous page, the page should then save the data to the local storage of the browser. This means if user clears the data in the browser, it will be lost forever.
   - When you load the next page from the server, just fetch the option from the local storage. It's easy...
     http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Furthermore:

- The data can be stored in cookies. Similar to local storage but will be sent to server with each HTTP request. This would be overhead if you don't need this data on the server. Use local storage instead.
- The data can be passed in the URL. Only if you want the user to be able to change this data.