# How to print result of Pyodide in another webpage instead of in console?

Tags: javascript, pyodide

I am using Pyodide to compile python code in the browser. The code below is used to execute the python code in `editor` and display the result in console. For the errors, I am displaying it using `alert()` as shown below, and it works just fine. Now, I want to change the behaviour of pyodide to display the result in another webpage. for example: `var resultWindow = window.open("resultPage.html"); resultWindow.document.write(output);`.

```js
function compilerResult() {
    try {
        pyodide.runPython(editor.doc.getValue())
    } catch(err) {
        alert(err)
    }
}
```

Comment: You could serialize your result (e.g. as string),  and include it in the request to your other page. Or use sessionStorage or localStorage https://stackoverflow.com/a/46785096/1791279