# How to pass data of selection box from one page to another using AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

What I want to do is when I choose an option from Selection box in page1 the value of that option will be shown in page 2.

Here is some code that I have tried so far:

App.js:

```
app.controller('mainController', function ($scope) {
    $scope.sizes = [
        { size: "35" },
        { size: "36" },
        { size: "37" },
        { size: "38" },
        { size: "38" },
    ];
});
```

In page1:

```
<select ng-model="selectedSize">
    <option ng-repeat="Size in sizes" value="{{Size.size}} "> {{Size.size}}
    </option>
</select>
```

In page2:

```
<p>{{selectedSize}}</p>
```

**Note: page1 and page2 have the same controller.**

I really need some help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: declare a variable in a service or factory and assign that value to that service and after that print that value on the second page. or you broadcast the data using rootScope.

Comment: As the data is serving from a single controller, what ever you wrote above is correct.Then why it is missing? can you tell us what you are doing  after selecting size. Thanks.

Comment: After selecting size, I go to page2 to check if the value is shown. The code would be correct if the line <p>{{selectedSize}}</p> was on page1. Since it is in page2, the value from the selection box option isn't shown.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)

Comment: hi please accept answer if it worked for you

Answer (score 0):

if you want to pass data from one page to another page , you can make use of

- QueryString
- SessionStorage, LocalStorage
- Cookies

Comment: i don't think that's necessary since both pages have the same controller

Comment: @SachilaRanawaka- but controller get initialize new for each page , right ? its not like service of angualr singleton

Comment: oh yeah, that makes sense. :)

Answer (score 0):

If page1 and page 2 are of same controller

- Try storing the value in scope variable.

If not in same controller

- Store it in $rootScope variable and access.
- If you would like to show the value in page2 URL. Try storing in a id in state url and access it using Stateparams.
- Else store in localStorage variable and clear it(if you don't want further).