# Ajax success value print in upcoming page

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms

I am using form which submit by ajax form submit. On success ajax submit i will change page to another file and also i need to print my success data in my upcoming page. Like `$.(home.html#main).append("some value ");` my form is in index.html file and i want to change my page to home.html

Comment: You can not do it. Either you need to add the message in the URL or set the message in the localstorage and retrieve it on any page you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)