# How to pass text from one page to another by clicking on div using JQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm making a school project and i am stuck here for almost a week. what i am trying to get is... I have 2 pages
PAGE 1 have more than five divs with different titles. I want to copy that specific title that the user clicks on and want to paste it on PAGE 2. I have tried so many ways but still not getting the answer.

```html
    <!--Page 1 Start-->
    <section class="main-content">
        <div class="blog-cards egypt">
            <div class="blog-card-details">
                <h2 class="card-title"><a href="#">Div 1</a></h2>
                <a href="#">Abū Sulţān </a><span>•</span><a href="#"> Egypt</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-cards london">
            <div class="blog-card-details">
                <h2 class="card-title"><a href="book-now.html">Div 2</a></h2>
                <a href="#">Kensington and Chelsea </a><span>•</span><a href="#"> London</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
    
    <!--Page 1 End-->
    <!--Page 2 Start-->
    <section class="page2-main">
        <h3 class="result-show-here"></h3>
    </section>
```

What i want is if i click Div 1 it will show text of .card-title on Page 2 .result-show-here. and if i click Div 2 it will show text of .card-title on Page 2 .result-show-here. and i don't want to change the class

Comment: Show your code attempt

Comment: What do you mean by "page"? What have you tried?

Comment: how can i show you. i am new here

Comment: Are the pages on another tab? If yes try with localstorage: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)

Comment: I just edited my answer. Please check. I hope I could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Use **localStorage** or **sessionStorage**:

```
$('div').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.text = $(this).find('a').val(); //or sessionStorage.text
});
```

and

```
$('.result-show-here').html(localStorage.text);//or sessionStorage.text
```

First create a page handler on your script using **jQuery**:

```
var pg
switch (pg) {
        case 'page1':
            //the code for page1
            break;
        case 'page2':
            //the code for page2
            break;
    }
```

**In your case:**

for page1:
on your **HTML-Page**:

```
<script>pg = 'page1';<script>
```

and in your **script**:

```
//the code for page1
$('div').on('click', function() {
    localStorage.text = $(this).find('a').val();
});
```

for page2:

on your **HTML-Page**:

```
<script>pg = 'page2';<script>
```

and in your **script**:

```
//the code for page2
$('.result-show-here').html(localStorage.text);
```

Based on your case.

I prefer to add a class on the a-tag like `<a class="city">London</a>`
and get the right value:

```
//the code for page1
    $('div').on('click', function() {
        localStorage.text = $(this).find('.city').val();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If your pages are hosted by some sort of webserver you can use [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/WebSockets) to communicate/share data.

If your pages are opened on the same machine/browser without any server i would recommend using the browsers session- or localstorage objects. 
To set a value use:

```
sessionStorage.myValue = 'value'
```

To get a value use:

```
var val = sessionStorage.myValue
```

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages).