# Display 'sum' on another page

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am currently having a problem displaying a calculated sum on the next page in javascript/html.

My calculation for defining the sum looks like this, where the 'sum + €' is displayed at the end.

```
function udregnPant() {


    let sum = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= pantListParsed.length; i++) {


        let totalPantKr = pantListParsed[i].aPantMoney + pantListParsed[i].bPantMoney + pantListParsed[i].cPantMoney;
        sum += totalPantKr;

        console.log(sum);
        document.getElementById('sumAfPantB').innerHTML = sum + " €.";
    }


}
```

In the following HTML input I want to display the sum as the value instead of '10 €'

```
 <input type="text" name="amount" id="text1" value="10 €." readonly/>
```

Appreciate your help!

Comment: You want calculate sum and send the result to another page?

Comment: No, I am already calculating the sum when hitting a button on my first page. But I want to display this sum in a textbox on the next page

Comment: So GeekZilva is right, then. You'll need to pass it to the page via query string or save it to `localStorage` or similar, and retrieve it on the target page.

Comment: How would the function for saving it to localStorage look like?

Answer (score 1):

Make use of web storage.

**sessionStorage** - stores data for one session

```
sessionStorage.getItem('label')
sessionStorage.setItem('label', 'value')
```

**localStorage** - stores data with no expiration date

```
localStorage.getItem('label')
localStorage.setItem('label', 'value')
```

Example

```
function setSum(value) {
    localStorage.setItem("sum", value);
}

function getSum() {
    return localStorage.getItem("sum");
}
```

[Live Example at JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/xubajoxiki/edit?html,js,output)

*References*

[Share data between html pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609376/share-data-between-html-pages)

[HTML5 Web Storage](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Answer (score 0):

1. After calculating your value, redirect the user to a URL with the value in the query string (See [Redirections in HTTP)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections) -- this may look something like

```
window.location = http://mysite/page2.html?amount=12
```

2. On the new page, retrieve the value from the query string using the `searchParams` property (see [URL.searchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)). Could look something like:

```
let params = (new URL(document.location)).searchParams;
document.getByElementId('text1').value = params.get('amount');
```

Comment: Other answers suggest using localStorage. This is a fine solution, but consider whether it may be overkill for your use case. If a query string works for you, and you're only passing one or two values, I would personally avoid cluttering the local Storage space.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little example using [local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage), since so doesnt allow local storage try it in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1nx068z/10/) and
the code sample as well:

```js
document.getElementById('btnSend').onclick = ()=>{
let total = document.getElementById('txtTotal').value;
if(!isNaN(total) && total > 0){
localStorage.setItem('total', total);
document.getElementById('txtTotal').value = '';
}
}
document.getElementById('btnLastTotal').onclick = ()=>{
var lastTotal = localStorage.getItem('total');
if(lastTotal !=undefined){
alert('last total is:'+lastTotal);
}else{
alert('No records found');
}
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtTotal">
<br>
<input type="button" id="btnSend" value="Save the total"> <input type="button" id="btnLastTotal" value="get Last Total">
```

Hope it helps